# Kendo scheduler, disable animations

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Has anyone figured out how to disable the modal animations in Kendo scheduler? I know it's not officially supported but I was hoping someone might have been able to hack this.

They are really slow on some of my clients' systems and it would be best if I could just disable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do:

```
window.kendo.effects.disable();
```

Which kendo says disables all effects.

I've noticed it doesn't on some controls but for the scheduler it seems to do.